# What paint for exterior door that bubbled

Tags: doors, paint, exterior

I had a urethaned fir, front door that last year I sanded down past the veneer due to weather damage. Now I was stuck using paint. After completely sanding down to bare wood, I used acrylic ext primer, and two coats of Benjamin Moore MoorGlo Soft Glow (also acrylic). I waited one day between each coat. I painted in fall in the Pacific NW, keeping it in a lightly heated garage with air circulation for about 25 days for it to cure before handling. Once I hung it, it fogged and severely bubbled. It also had bad brush strokes. I added Floetrol to it but it didn't help. This is a south facing door by the way. I don't know if it was just too humid to dry properly? I had a contractor come out to bid on redoing it, but they are booked through Oct. He said I should have used an oil-based primer even though I used acrylic paint. This doesn't make sense to me, so looking for input. I also heard from another contractor who also couldn't make it out any time soon that because the paint is dark, it probably got hot and that's why it may have bubbled. I have resigned myself to doing this job again. I want to make sure I get it right this time. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: A bubble that large suggests to me that the paint never really bonded well in that spot, and possibly others yet to show themselves. You mention the door was urethane coated? Did you sand the entire door down? If you didn’t the paint might not bond to unsanded urethane, especially if it had a high gloss. Acrylic paint might not bond to urethane well at all, sanded or not...

Comment: Thank you Paul. I did sand the door down all the way, but wood being porous, I can see that it's entirely possible that there was still urethane (semi-gloss) there. I'm going to use oil this time.